# Can i slop div vertically with css like in the image

Tags: html, css

[I want to slop div vertically with css like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOMne.jpg)

Comment: Please provide more details. It is very difficult to help you with the question being in its current state. When you hover over the "vote up" button it says "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear". Please change your question to fulfill that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If i understood your question. You can get image and give it `position: relative;` 
After that you should create few divs and give them `position: absolute` and give to div next styles:

```css
.block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  margin-left: 100px;
  opacity: .5;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class = "block"></div>
```